# sbt: finding correct path to files/folders under resources directory

Tags: scala, apache-spark, build, sbt

I've a simple project structure:

> WordCount
>   |
>   |------------ project
>   |----------------|---assembly.sbt
>   |
>   |------------ resources
>   |------------------|------ Message.txt
>   |
>   |------------ src
>   |--------------|---main
>   |--------------------|---scala
>   |--------------------------|---org
>   |-------------------------------|---apache
>   |----------------------------------------|---spark
>   |----------------------------------------------|---Counter.scala
>   |
>   |------------ build.sbt

here's how `Counter.scala` looks:

```
package org.apache.spark

object Counter {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf())
        val path: String = getClass.getClassLoader.getResource("Message.txt").getPath
        println(s"path = $path")
//      val lines = sc.textFile(path)
//      val wordsCount = lines
//          .flatMap(line => line.split("\\s", 2))
//          .map(word => (word, 1))
//          .reduceByKey(_ + _)
//
//      wordsCount.foreach(println)
    }
}
```

notice that the commented lines are actually correct, but the `path` variable is not. After building the fat jar with `sbt assembly` and running it with `spark-submit`, to see the value of `path`, I get:

```
path = file:/home/me/WordCount/target/scala-2.11/Counter-assembly-0.1.jar!/Message.txt
```

you can see that `path` is assigned to the jar location and, mysteriously, followed by `!/` and then the file name `Message.txt`!!
on the other hand when I'm inside the WordCount folder, and I run the repl `sbt console` and then write

```
scala> getClass.getClassLoader.getResource("Message.txt").getPath
```

I get the correct path (without the `file:/` prefix)

```
res1: String = /home/me/WordCount/target/scala-2.11/classes/Message.txt
```

**Question:**
1 - why is there two different outputs from the same command? (i.e. `getClass.getClassLoader.getResource("...").getPath`)
2 - how can I use the correct path, which appears in the console, inside my source file `Counter.scala`?

---

for anyone who wants to try it, here's my `build.sbt`:

```
name := "Counter"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

resourceDirectory in Compile := baseDirectory.value / "resources"

// allows us to include spark packages
resolvers += "bintray-spark-packages" at "https://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/"
resolvers += "Typesafe Simple Repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/simple/maven-releases/"
resolvers += "MavenRepository" at "https://mvnrepository.com/"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.4.0" % "provided"
```

and the spark-submit command is:

```
spark-submit --master local --deploy-mode client --class org.apache.spark.Counter /home/me/WordCount/target/scala-2.11/Counter-assembly-0.1.jar
```

Comment: I've already looked for solutions everywhere, including previous answers here in SO, with no luck!

Comment: also `getClass.getResource()` is always `null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1 - why is there two different outputs from the same command?

By command, I am assuming you mean `getClass.getClassLoader.getResource("Message.txt").getPath`. So I would rephrase the question as why does the same method call to classloader `getResource(...)` return two different result depending on `sbt console` vs `spark-submit`.

The answer is because they use different classloader with each having different classpath. `console` uses your directories as classpath while `spark-submit` uses the fat JAR, which includes resources. When a resource is found in a JAR, the classloader returns **a JAR URL**, which looks like `jar:file:/home/me/WordCount/target/scala-2.11/Counter-assembly-0.1.jar!/Message.txt`.

The whole point of using Apache Spark is to distribute some work across multiple computers, so I don't think you want to see your machine's local path in production.